# Powershell will not return a hash table key value

Tags: powershell

I have a variable that is a hash table:

```
PS C:\depot\code\rp4vm> $skey


key              value
---              -----
Splitter version 5.2.P1(a.362)
OS version       VMkernel na1-pdesx09
```

I am trying to access the values for the keys but I cannot seem to. No matter how I address them I get nothing:

```
PS C:\depot\code\rp4vm> $skey."Splitter version"

PS C:\depot\code\rp4vm> $skey["Splitter version"]
```

I checked to see if it had key and value pairs:

```
PS C:\depot\code\rp4vm> $skey.key

Splitter version
OS version
PS C:\depot\code\rp4vm> $skey.value

5.2.P1(a.362)
VMkernel na1-pdesx09.americas.global-legal.com
```

I am running PowerShell 7 and nothing else appears to have changed in the help files on how to handle hash tables. Does anyone have an idea as to how  I can capture the information?

Comment: What type is it?  `$skey.gettype()`

Comment: I suspect that there is either a special character (as a no-break-space), a `$null` in front of the list or ait concerns a different structure (e.g. list of key/value pairs). To figure out the actual content you might want to try this [ConvertTo-Expression](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) cmdlet: `ConvertTo-Expression $skey`

Comment: @ js2010 Here is the type 
`IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array`

Comment: @iRon I get nothing back on ConvertTo-Expression

Comment: @AndrewMadsen - if you type `$SKey.` to bring up the autocomplete/intellisense list, then scroll to the bottom of that list ... what you do you see listed? when i recreate your hashtable, i see `'Splitter version'` & `'OS version'` listed. i suspect you will see something different. ///// also, if you do `$SKey.GetEnumerator().Name[0] | Format-Hex` do you see any unexpected characters in the listing?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I do not see anything in the list except the regular things I would expect. as for the Format-Hex command I get this:
`PS C:\depot\code\rp4vm> $SKey.GetEnumerator().Name[0] | Format-Hex

Format-Hex: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.`

Comment: Looks like you have an array of PSObjects with properties `key` and `value`. So not a Hashtable at all.

Comment: Try: `System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($skey)`

Comment: @AndrewMadsen - your hashtable is ... not a hashtable. [*grin*] it looks like  `Theo` has you covered on the problem, so i will drop out. good luck!

Comment: What is `$skey[0].gettype()`?  pscustomobject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is definitely **not** a Hashtable. More likely it is an array of **objects** that have properties `key` and `value` like this

```
$skey = [PsCustomObject]@{'key' = 'Splitter version'; 'value' = '5.2.P1(a.362)'},
        [PsCustomObject]@{'key' = 'OS version'; 'value' = 'VMkernel na1-pdesx09'}
```

To demonstrate:

```
$skey | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host ('{0} = {1}' -f $_.key, $_.value)
}
```

Should show

```
Splitter version = 5.2.P1(a.362)
OS version = VMkernel na1-pdesx09
```

You can convert to a Hashtable if you like:

```
$hash = @{}
$skey | ForEach-Object {
    $hash[$_.key] = $_.value
}
```

<sup>Typing this on mobile, so hopefully got the formatting right..</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To complement the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61550045/1701026) from @Theo, I suspect that is actually concerns a list of [`KeyValuePair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netcore-3.1) objects, like:

```
$skey = 
    (new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[String, String]' 'Splitter version', '5.2.P1(a.362)'),
    (new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[String, String]' 'OS version', 'VMkernel na1-pdesx09'),
    (new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[String, String]' 'OS version', 'VMkernel na2-other')
```

Anyways, the difference between a hash table and a list of `[KeyValuePair]` (or `[pscustomobject]`) objects is that a list of objects doesn't require unique keys (as shown in the example above). Meaning that the problem could be that converting them to a hash table, might overwrite duplicate keys.

To retrieve the specific key from the list use:

```
($skey | Where key -eq 'Splitter version').Value
5.2.P1(a.362)
```

or multiple keys:

```
($skey | Where key -eq 'OS version').Value
VMkernel na1-pdesx09
VMkernel na2-other
```